# Don't recreate the main site room after deletion

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat

Whenever there is a new site, [Stack Exchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/stack-exchange) creates a room for it, and posts:

> Welcome to chat for: [site]
>
> This is a general discussion room, but please feel free to create more subject-specific rooms (a single room with every possible discussion isn't very helpful)
>
> For playing with chat features:
>
> [Sandbox onebox]
>
> and remember; please read the [FAQ] ;p)

Which is a pretty good service. Another thing it does is that it re-creates the room if deleted.

Another job of Stack Exchange's is to [freeze or delete old rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention).

Now, put these two together and you get:

[image]

(See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&nohide=true&host=*), 10k chat and chat mod only)

Looks like the SE bot is deleting these rooms as they get old, then noticing that the room is missing, and re-creating it.

This seems icky to me. I propose that the system either stop deleting the main chatroom, or it should stop recreating it.

Comment: It's also weird that it creates a room for "The Stack Exchange Network"—and posts a message saying "(a single room with *every possible discussion* isn't very helpful)".

Comment: I undeleted it and posted enough messages to forestall auto-deletion. Hopefully this will prevent it from recreating it repeatedly, as a workaround.