# Main chat room for a newer site still freezes due to inactivity

Tags: feature-request, chat

According to:

- [Exclude the main chat room from automatic freezing/deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100519/707129)

> This is now implemented. Main chat rooms do not freeze automatically due to inactivity.

This isn’t true. The [Drones chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106718/droning-on) froze from inactivity recently. The [Tezos chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/88974) is also frozen.

Can the newer sites have this feature implemented please?

Comment: A few other post here or on per-site metas, where you can find a bit more: 
[Why is the main chat room frozen?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/343),
 [Don't freeze a chatroom soon after a mod has unfrozen it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130472),
[Main chatroom for a SE site and chatroom pruning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226302).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The age of the site has nothing to do with it. There is no concept of a main site room for the freezing logic - it simply won't freeze the last remaining room parented to a specific site (that is not a room created between two users or created from a comment chain).

In the Drones.SE case, for instance, you have the [HNQ feed room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/107719). If this is active, and the "main" room reaches the criteria for freezing... the main one will be frozen.

But the age of the site has nothing to do with it.